# why are all files created by pipe in Windows owned by administrators

Tags: pipe, command-prompt

When I pipe the output from a command in Windows to a file it is always owned by BUILTIN\Administrators user.

For example if I run the following at a Windows Command Prompt:

```
dir > mydir.txt
```

then run:

```
dir /q
```

I get:  1,695 BUILTIN\Administrators mydir.txt

I can use takeown /f mydir.txt    to give ownership to my account but I want the mydir.txt file to owned by my account when it is created.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This happens if a file is created from _elevated_ command prompt (run `cmd` as administrator).

Comment: Yes, that is a better way of stating it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague supplied the answer so I thought I'd share.  My user ID is part of the Adminitrators group so Windows assigns the BUILTIN\Administrators group as the user in case other Administrators on the computer need access to the file.